# System hangs when running two different LKMs to get battery statistics every second

Tags: c, linux-kernel, batterymanager

I am developing a Linux Kernel Module (LKM) which analyzes my laptop's battery parameters and writes to Kernel log file (/var/log/kern.log) for every given time interval. Using the data from log file, I will be plotting a real time graph.

You may think as why I am doing this stuff. This is a part of my academics is the answer to it. Also, I find this a pretty interesting one.

My entire analysis for this task went on simple, until recently. The steps I followed are:

1. The parameters can be fetched as given in the best answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858657/how-can-i-obtain-battery-level-inside-a-linux-kernel-module) and some more parameters were found [here](http://arunmurthy.blogspot.in/2010/02/hints-for-writing-battery-driver-in.html). Using these two links, my task got an easy start.
2. The code to execute a function of LKM at a periodic time was fetched from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920238/reliability-of-linux-kernel-add-timer-at-resolution-of-one-jiffy/17055867#17055867). This was modified to run for every second.

With these two LKMs, I misunderstood that my task was a piece of cake, as the only task left out was combining these two LKMs and writing the required parameter data to log file.

I clubbed the code of both the LKMs and made one single LKM, and plugged it into my kernel of Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit OS. The system froze instantly making me shocked. I was clueless at this point.

After this I reduced the code of battery analyzer LKM and timer LKM which are least required to be run for my desired output. I found the reduced code which runs comfortably.

Later I migrated the code to analyze battery parameters to a function and exported it (using `EXPORT_SYMBOL(<function_name>)`, to be called from the timer method. I was damn sure that this would run for sure, as both the LKMs were running cool.

I would like to give you the real picture of what happened in my machine with following LKM codes and video.

**bat_stat_analyzer.c** - LKM to fetch battery parameters and write to kernel log file.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/version.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/kdev_t.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/power_supply.h>

static int result = 0;
static struct power_supply *psy;
static void bat_stat(void);

EXPORT_SYMBOL(bat_stat);

static void bat_stat(void) {
  union power_supply_propval value;
  int charge_status, voltage_now, current_now, capacity;

  psy = power_supply_get_by_name("BAT1");
  result = psy->get_property(psy,POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_STATUS, &value);
  charge_status = (!result) ? value.intval : -1;
  result = psy->get_property(psy,POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_VOLTAGE_NOW, &value);
  voltage_now = (!result) ? value.intval : -1;
  result = psy->get_property(psy,POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_CURRENT_NOW, &value);
  current_now = (!result) ? value.intval : -1;
  result = psy->get_property(psy,POWER_SUPPLY_PROP_CAPACITY, &value);
  capacity = (!result) ? value.intval : -1;

  printk(KERN_INFO "%s:%d,%d,%d,%d\n",
    __func__, charge_status, voltage_now, current_now, capacity);
}

static int __init bat_stat_init(void) /* Constructor */
{
  bat_stat();
  return 0;
}

static void __exit bat_stat_exit(void) /* Destructor */
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Good bye\n");
}

module_init(bat_stat_init);
module_exit(bat_stat_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Sriram Kumar <sriramhearing_at_gmail_dot_com>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("First Battery Analyzer");
```

**bat_stat_repeater.c** - LKM to call a function repeatedly

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>     /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/hrtimer.h>

static unsigned long period_ms;
static unsigned long period_ns;
static ktime_t ktime_period_ns;
static struct hrtimer my_hrtimer;
extern int bat_stat(void);


//~ static void bat_stat_repeat(unsigned long data)
static enum hrtimer_restart bat_stat_repeat(struct hrtimer *timer)
{
  unsigned long tjnow;
  ktime_t kt_now;
  bat_stat();
  printk(KERN_INFO "Repeating...\n");

  tjnow = jiffies;
  kt_now = hrtimer_cb_get_time(&my_hrtimer);
  hrtimer_forward(&my_hrtimer, kt_now, ktime_period_ns);
  return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

static int __init bat_stat_init(void)
{
  struct timespec tp_hr_res;
  period_ms = 1000;
  hrtimer_get_res(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp_hr_res);

  hrtimer_init(&my_hrtimer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
  my_hrtimer.function = &bat_stat_repeat;
  period_ns = period_ms*( (unsigned long)1E6L );
  ktime_period_ns = ktime_set(0,period_ns);
  hrtimer_start(&my_hrtimer, ktime_period_ns, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit bat_stat_exit(void)
{
  int ret_cancel = 0;
  while( hrtimer_callback_running(&my_hrtimer) ) {
    ret_cancel++;
  }
  if (ret_cancel != 0) {
    printk(KERN_INFO " testjiffy Waited for hrtimer callback to finish (%d)\n", ret_cancel);
  }
  if (hrtimer_active(&my_hrtimer) != 0) {
    ret_cancel = hrtimer_cancel(&my_hrtimer);
    printk(KERN_INFO " testjiffy active hrtimer cancelled: %d\n", ret_cancel);
  }
  if (hrtimer_is_queued(&my_hrtimer) != 0) {
    ret_cancel = hrtimer_cancel(&my_hrtimer);
    printk(KERN_INFO " testjiffy queued hrtimer cancelled: %d\n", ret_cancel);
  }
  printk(KERN_INFO "Exit testjiffy\n");
}

module_init(bat_stat_init);
module_exit(bat_stat_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

The **Makefile** I used looked like below as it was used to compile both of the LKMs.

```
obj-m := <file_name>.o
KDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```

The output that I obtained using these two LKMs can be viewed on this youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RUWk5M1TNLg) (just 2 mins video). If you wish to see it as an image, it is attached below:

[image: Screenshot of battery analyzer output. System getting halted.]

I would like to know:

- Is there a better and/or easier way to achieve what I am trying? or
- What's the trouble in my LKMs that make my CPU get choked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside, can you do your initial, high-risk tests in a VM? If you cause a VM to 'splode it's not _nearly_ as harmful as causing this to your actual system.

Comment: Initially VM was tried, but the battery information was not available to the VM OS via the VM Manager (Virtual box).

Comment: Battery info is not even available when the VB guest additions are installed?

Comment: I got my working LKM anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a problem because of using `hrtimers`. This mechanism is designed for high precision, the callback is called in hardirq context (with IRQs disabled) so your callback function has to be atomic. Yet, the functions you are calling from the callback are not atomic and may sleep (because of mutexes). Normal timers have similar problems so in order to fix this, you should use some other way or repeating task, like workqueues, for example.

Some other small problems in your code:

- your `batt_stat` function declarations in both modules are different
- you don't check the output of power_supply_get_by_name() in first module

Also, I really don't see any reason to split this to two kernel modules, you should use only one.

Comment: Thanks for those points Krzysztof Adamski. I will try using an alternative.

 - `bat_stat` function was little modified and I missed to change it in another file. Thanks for that.
 - I have analyzed the output of `power_supply_get_by_name()` to be safe everytime. I will check if any condition can be used for it.

As I didn't get working with one single module, I splitted them and started to use as different modules.

Comment: I removed the timer LKM and repeated the battery statistics analyzer with `kthread` and applied infinite looping with the help of `msleep` to impose delay in the execution. I also applied a small logic to the (infinite) loop such that the thread will terminate when the module is removed from the kernel. Thanks for the tips Krzysztof Adamski!

Comment: I had a thought that you actually showed an alternative way to get the solution. Later it hit me... `The best answer`